# Running select() socket and timers in the same linux thread

Tags: c, linux, sockets, select, timer

I am writing code on ucLinux for socket communication. I use `select()` for reading the data on sockets. I also have a 20 msec timer (created using `setitimer`) running in the same thread for performing a parallel operation. My select function gets blocked each time saying "Interrupted by system call", since it receives the SIGALRM signal issue by the timer on overflow, every 20 msec. I tried restarting the system when EINTR is issued, and run `select()` again. but this wont help, since i will always receive the SIGALRM by timer every 20 msec. I dont want to ignore this signal since it is used for performing other tasks in the system, but i want to use select without being affected by this signal. Is there any way to handle this? I cannot use functions like `timer_create()` as these are not supported on the platform I am using. So, I am stuck up with using `setitimer`for timer creation. Is there any way I can run both together independently in my code?

Answer (score 4):

What you're doing is pretty weird. Let's face it: timers are an ancient and mostly-obsolete mechanism for doing work. Pretty much everyone these days avoids signals like the plague. There's essentially nothing useful you can do in a signal callback (you certainly can't call anything complicated like `malloc` for example), so you must have some way to get the timer notification back from the `SIGALRM` handler to the main thread already -- you're not actually *doing the work in the signal handler* are you?

So you have two tactics: use the standard self-pipe trick to turn the signal into an event on an fd, the "normal" way to handle things like `SIGTERM`, `SIGINT` and so on. You call `socketpair` or `pipe` to make a pipe, then write a byte into the pipe from the signal handler. You read the byte back from you `select` loop. You commonly write the value of the signal as the data, but you could write anything really.

The other tactic (much more sane) is to avoid the mess with signals and `setitimer` completely. `setitimer` is seriously legacy and causes problems for all sorts of things (eg. it can cause functions like `getaddrinfo` to hang, a bug that still hasn't been fixed in glibc (http://www.cygwin.org/frysk/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15819). Signals are bad for your health. So the "normal" tactic is to use the timeout argument to `select`. You have a linked list of timers, objects you use to manager periodic events in your code. When you call `select`, you use as the timeout the shortest of your remaining timers. When the `select` call returns, you check if any timers are expired and call the timer handler as well as the handlers for your fd events. That's a standard application event loop. This way your loop code so you can listen for timer-driven events as well as fd-driven events. Pretty much every application on your system uses some variant on this mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Is an option for you doing something like this?

```C
While(1) {
   int rc = select(nfds, &readfds, &writefds, &exceptfds, &timeout);
   if ((rc < 0) && (errno == EINTR) )
      continue;
   else {
      // some instructions
   }
}
```

If this is not an option for you you can probably use **pselect** which adds a parameter to the end (sigmask) which specifies a set of signals that should be blocked during the pselect(), see [here](http://lwn.net/Articles/176911/)

Comment: Hi,
thanks for your suggestion. I already did that. but, the problem is it keeps looping in the select, since it keeps getting EINTR by the system after every 20 msec, which is the period of the timer running on the same thread.So, I have a select function that keeps running, getting interrupted and running again, and eventually ends up reading nothing on the sockets, just keeps looping giving out the interrupted call signal.
Any way to avoid this? I need the timer in the same thread, i cant ignore the timer signal, nor can i block the select function. Any way of achieving both?

Comment: @user2069669 added reference to pselect, you can use instead of select